# Entity Framework. How to add object to collection in Unchanged state

Tags: .net, entity-framework

How to add object to a collection so that after .SaveChanges() it hasn't inserted/updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Attach` instead of `Add`.

Comment: Then read the [MSDN documentation on Attaching and Detaching Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896271.aspx).